# How do I get a count of items in one column that match items in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume I have two data tables and a linking table as such:

```
A         B         A_B_Link          
-----     -----     -----
ID        ID        A_ID
Name      Name      B_ID
```

2 Questions:

1. I would like to write a query so that I have all of A's columns and a count of how many B's are linked to A, what is the best way to do this?
2. Is there a way to have a query return a row with all of the columns from A and a column containing *all* of linked names from B (maybe separated by some delimiter?)

Note that **the query must return distinct rows from A**, so a simple left outer join is not going to work here...I'm guessing I'll need nested select statements?

Comment: You should post two questions on stack overflow - your questions are not related and you won't get good answers grouping them like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, COUNT(ab.B_ID) AS bcount
FROM A LEFT JOIN A_B_Link ab ON (ab.A_ID = A.ID)
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Name;
```

This outputs one row per row of A, with the count of matching B's.  Note that you must list all columns of A in the GROUP BY statement; there's no way to use a wildcard here.

An alternate solution is to use a correlated subquery, as @Ray Booysen shows:

```
SELECT A.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A_B_Link 
   WHERE A_B_Link.A_ID = A.A_ID) AS bcount
FROM A;
```

This works, but correlated subqueries aren't very good for performance.

For your second question, you need something like MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function.  In MySQL, you can get a comma-separated list of `B.Name` per row of A like this:

```
SELECT A.*, GROUP_CONCAT(B.Name) AS bname_list
FROM A 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN A_B_Link ab ON (A.ID = ab.A_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON (ab.B_ID = B.ID)
GROUP BY A.ID;
```

There's no easy equivalent in Microsoft SQL Server.  Check here for another question on SO about this:
"[Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-groupconcat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)"

Or Google for '[microsoft SQL server "group_concat"](http://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+sql+server+%22group_concat%22)' for a variety of other solutions.

Comment: Good catch bill, I wasn't too sure on your solution so I went with what I knew. ;)

Answer (score 3):

For #1

```
SELECT A.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A_B_Link WHERE A_B_Link.A_ID = AOuter.A_ID)
FROM A as AOuter
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B_ID)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN A_B_Link ab ON ab.A_ID=A.ID
```

Comment: I think you are missing a GROUP BY statement.